# Select multiple entries to database

Tags: php, moodle

Having mform field elements id and page:

Form element1 = id as textfield with name 'id'

Form element2 = page as select multiple field with name 'pagebuilt'. Trying to run the form, page_id stores 0 values.

```
$mform->addElement('text', 'id', get_string('user', 'user'));
$mform->setType('id', PARAM_INT);       

$select = $mform->addElement('select', 'pagebuilt', get_string('pageide'), array('red', 'blue', 'green'));
$select->setMultiple(true);

$this->add_action_buttons();
-----------------------------
$mform     = new page_form();
$formdata  = $mform->get_data(); 
$id        = $formdata->id;
$page      = $formdata->pagebuilt;
$DB->insert_record('pagetable', $formdata);
```

I could store $id to database and could not store $page. How could I insert one per row into database. Appreciate your suggestions.

pagetable:

```
id    page_id
----  -------
2       0
4       0
7       0
```

Looking for moodle logic.

Comment: are you getting `page_id` as a parameter from your form? because your column name is page_id and your passing `pagebuilt`. try to change it to `page_id` and check.

Comment: pagebuilt is form element name and page_id is a table column. Want to insert pagebuilt values to page_id

Comment: you can change it in your form. or you can copy this instance to another and modified property `$copyObj->page_id = $b->pagebuilt;` and pass this copy instance to insert into table.

Comment: Could you explain me in detail.Would be helpful to all moodlers

Comment: replace `$select = $mform->addElement('select', 'pagebuilt', get_string('pageide'), array('red', 'blue', 'green'));`  with `$select = $mform->addElement('select', 'page_id', get_string('pageide'), array('red', 'blue', 'green'));`

Comment: I couldn't find any difference if I replace page_id with pagebuilt. pagebuilt is form element name and page_id is a table column. Want to insert pagebuilt values to page_id

Comment: yes because you are not binding page_id value from anywhere, either its come to form for you can modified your object instance to insert it.